# dotnet restore error on simple yo project

Tags: .net-core, yo

Running on `Fedorea 26`, I am building my first `dotnet core asp` application. Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/microservices) tutorial, when I try the command below of `dotnet restore` I get an error
below.

I have a suspicion that the problem is that `yo` builds an `dotnet core 1.x` application, but as seen below, I have `dotnet core 2.0.0`.

**Is this correct, and if so, how do I upgrade `yo` to build dotnet 2.0 projects?**

```
yo aspnet

 _-----_     ╭──────────────────────────╮
|       |    │      Welcome to the      │
|--(o)--|    │  marvellous ASP.NET Core │
```

`---------´   │        generator!        │
    ( _´U`_ )    ╰──────────────────────────╯
    /***A***\   /
     |  ~  |
   **'._**.'__
 ´   `|° ´ Y`

```
? What type of application do you want to create? Empty Web Application
? What's the name of your ASP.NET application? WeatherMicroservice
   create WeatherMicroservice/.gitignore
   create WeatherMicroservice/Program.cs
   create WeatherMicroservice/Startup.cs
   create WeatherMicroservice/WeatherMicroservice.csproj
   create WeatherMicroservice/web.config
   create WeatherMicroservice/Properties/launchSettings.json
   create WeatherMicroservice/runtimeconfig.template.json
   create WeatherMicroservice/README.md
   create WeatherMicroservice/global.json


Your project is now created, you can use the following commands to get going
    cd "WeatherMicroservice"
    dotnet restore
    dotnet build (optional, build will also happen when it's run)
    dotnet run


[idf@localhost asp-core]$ cd WeatherMicroservice/
[idf@localhost WeatherMicroservice]$ dotnet restore

The specified SDK version [1.0.0-rc4-004771] from global.json [/home/idf/Documents/asp-core/WeatherMicroservice/global.json] not found; install specified SDK version
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from: 
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

This is the version of `dotnet` installed:

```
[idf@localhost WeatherMicroservice]$ dotnet --info output:
The specified SDK version [1.0.0-rc4-004771] from global.json [/home/idf/Documents/asp-core/WeatherMicroservice/global.json] not found; install specified SDK version

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.0
  Build    : e8b8861ac7faf042c87a5c2f9f2d04c98b69f28d

[idf@localhost WeatherMicroservice]$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo is still on [ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC4](https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet). Also there is a request [ticket](https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet/issues/944) to upgrade to .NET Core 2.0.

Probably your best option is to use `dotnet new`. 
You can type `dotnet new -l` to list all available templates. For empty web app project `dotnet new web`.
You can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore2x) link for more info about `dotnet new`.

Answer (score 3):

Open file global.json
Please see what written in:

```
{
"sdk": {
"version": "xxx.yyy.zzz"
}
}
```

now, open console and write down:

```
dotnet --version
```

You need write this version in your json file

Comment: it won't work. 
when he tries to run it it will try to run the latest SDK and fail.